# How to reset user password in Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working in c# with firebase and i need to send a password reset mail.

According to the Firebase documentation it is with this code:

```
var email = "user@example.com";
var link = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.GeneratePasswordResetLinkAsync(
    email, actionCodeSettings);
// Construct email verification template, embed the link and send
// using custom SMTP server.
SendCustomEmail(email, displayName, link);
```

But it returns the error: ***FirebaseAuth does not contain a definition for DefaultInstance***

[image]

Does anyone know another way to send a reset email to the user? Thank You!

Comment: From https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/firebase-auth, it looks like you might need  `Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.GetAuth` instead?